# Mysterious Invalid Syntax in Field Calculation

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I'm trying to calculate a field in Model Builder using the Calculate Field tool. I'm using the following code block and expression in the calculation, but am getting an "invalid syntax (, line 1)" error.

```
# Code Block:
def get_block(block_id):
    block_only = str(block_id)[1:]
    if block_only[-1].isalpha():
        return block_only.zfill(3)
    else:
        return block_only.zfill(2)

# Expression:
get_block(%block_id%)
```

**%block_id%** is an in-line substitution that points to a string variable I create as the output of a custom Python script tool. Any ideas what the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the in-line substitution to pass the string variable.

The expression should read:

```
 get_block('%block_id%')
```

or

```
 get_block("%block_id%")
```

See the caution note in this help topic:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000004000000

Comment: Ah, yes, that must be it. Will verify tomorrow when I'm back at work. Thanks!

Comment: Just made the change and it worked perfectly. Thank you, again.